# I need to divide one cell through a summary of other cells (blank and not blank)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have in cells C to G names of employees. In column H I have a total of the production performed. I need to divide cell H through cells C to G to get the total production per employee.
I know it is easy but somehow I can't remember the right formula
Can you help?

Comment: Hi, could you share us with s simple sample?

Answer (score 0):

The total amount of employees is

```
=COUNTA(C2:G2)   ...counting all non-blank cells in C to G
```

So the average production per employee is

```
=H2/COUNTA(C2:G2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are amazing that you captured right away my need. I can't believe that I did not remember it myself.

Comment: @Fessi kindly checkmark the solution so others my know it has been solved!